# I got my system tethered to my iPhone but cannot find the IP address so I can ssh in

Tags: iphone, hot-spot

Newbie here. How do i find the IP address of my hotspot connection?

**$iwconfig** gives me this

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Rollie's iPhone X"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: E6:D6:18:FE:A3:76
          Bit Rate=24 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-35 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

**$ip addr show** gives me this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:99:dc:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.72/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 31533995sec preferred_lft 31533995sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe99:dc72/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:99:dc:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Is it connected via WLAN oder ethernet? From the output, `10.0.1.72` looks like a good candidate.